# Play FLV videos in Ubuntu 16.04: what's the (gstreamer?) package(s) I need to install to make Totem do it without error?

Tags: 16.04, codecs, totem, gstreamer, flv

I thought I had installed all "proprietary" codecs now via double-clicking some of my videos, and Totem asking me to install packages. However there's a kind of videos which don't prompt me to install packages and are not being played by Totem (they used to work on previous versions of Ubuntu, don't remember how), they just give the error `Internal data stream error`, and nothing gets printed in the console if I run totem from it.

So how to install **flv** codecs for Totem in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

I've tried with the following:

```
$ sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-*
```

However, it gives this error:

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-amr' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-videosink' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-alsa' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-dbg' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-doc' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-hybris:i386' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-tools' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-good' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-qapt' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-espeak' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-nice' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-videosource' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-crystalhd' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-base' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-audiosource' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-videoparsers' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-really-bad' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-clutter' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-pocketsphinx' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-dbg' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-doc' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-visualization' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-faad' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-lame' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-x' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-vaapi-doc' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-libav' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-dbg' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-good-dbg' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-doc' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-good-doc' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-dvswitch' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-vaapi' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-libav-dbg' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-packagekit' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-ffmpeg' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-doc' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
Note, selecting 'gstreamer1.0-audiosink' for glob 'gstreamer1.0-*'
gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0 is already the newest version (3.0.18-1).
gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0 set to manually installed.
gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly is already the newest version (1.8.0-1ubuntu1).
gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-amr is already the newest version (1.8.0-1ubuntu1).
gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-amr set to manually installed.
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base is already the newest version (1.8.1-1ubuntu0.1).
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base set to manually installed.
gstreamer1.0-libav is already the newest version (1.8.1-1~ubuntu1).
gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio is already the newest version (1.8.1-1ubuntu0.1).
gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio set to manually installed.
gstreamer1.0-tools is already the newest version (1.8.1-1~ubuntu1).
gstreamer1.0-tools set to manually installed.
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps is already the newest version (1.8.1-1ubuntu0.1).
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps set to manually installed.
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good is already the newest version (1.8.1-1ubuntu0.1).
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good set to manually installed.
gstreamer1.0-x is already the newest version (1.8.1-1ubuntu0.1).
gstreamer1.0-x set to manually installed.
gstreamer1.0-alsa is already the newest version (1.8.1-1ubuntu0.1).
gstreamer1.0-alsa set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gstreamer1.0-hybris:i386 : Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0:i386 (< 1.8.1) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libmedia1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 gstreamer1.0-libav-dbg : Depends: gstreamer1.0-libav (= 1.8.0-1) but 1.8.1-1~ubuntu1 is to be installed
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-dbg : Depends: gstreamer1.0-alsa (= 1.8.0-1ubuntu1) but 1.8.1-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
                                 Depends: gstreamer1.0-plugins-base (= 1.8.0-1ubuntu1) but 1.8.1-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
                                 Depends: gstreamer1.0-x (= 1.8.0-1ubuntu1) but 1.8.1-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
                                 Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 (= 1.8.0-1ubuntu1) but 1.8.1-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-good-dbg : Depends: gstreamer1.0-plugins-good (= 1.8.0-1ubuntu1) but 1.8.1-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
                                 Depends: gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio (= 1.8.0-1ubuntu1) but 1.8.1-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
 gstreamer1.0-vaapi : Depends: libva-drm1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libva-wayland1 (>= 1.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libva-x11-1 (>= 1.0.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Thanks

Comment: You could try installing VLC media player (from the software center, or with `sudo apt-get install vlc`), which will play flv videos.

Comment: I'm asking about TOTEM precisely because I don't want a different player

Comment: Run the application from a terminal.  If there are any errors, please include them in your question.

Comment: The install should be $  `sudo apt-get update &&  sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-*`  ... I.e. lots of updates these days ,,, until 16.04 gets more stable. So before every package install, please do `sudo apt-get update` -

Comment: @DanglingPointer nothing gets printed, updated question (note: I've already found a solution, posted as an answer)

Comment: @KnudLarsen thanks but that prompted the same apt errors, anyway I've fixed it now by installing one specific gstreamer package, see my own answer, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, installing this one fixed the problem:

```
sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-vaapi
```

Comment: Confirming that this worked for me (using parole player). parole tried to add support for H.264 by installing gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-videoparsers but it just looped on installing/rechecking. I exited and did this install and parole works. Can't speak about other players tho.